# How to read cross-origin CSS rules with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, cross-domain-policy, web-console

I am trying to use `document.styleSheets[i].cssRules` in the JavaScript console to read loaded CSS files of a tab. However, more often than not, I get the error: `CSSStyleSheet.cssRules getter: Not allowed to access cross-origin stylesheet`.

I figured out that cross-domain CSS rules can be only rendered, but not read with JavaScript, probably to prevent some kinds of XSS attacks. I tried to bypass this by using [CORS Everywhere](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cors-everywhere/) extension for Firefox, which I have already used for some cross-domain AJAX requests for data scraping from the JS console, where it worked fine. However, it didn't work for reading CSS rules. I also tried some similar extensions for Chrome, but I got similar error message, and extensions changed nothing about it.

Is there a way to make the browser give JS the read to the already loaded CSS rules in an already loaded tab?

If I just find URLs of stylesheets and try to read them with AJAX requests (which I *can* do), the server might respond with different files. I am interested in reading the already loaded CSS rules for the already loaded HTML in an already loaded tab.

Comment: There's always the `content.cors.disable` flag in about:config, but the real answer is a question: "It depends: what are you trying to *achieve*?", because it's entirely possible that using JS to manipulate CSSRules is nowhere near the best solution (e.g. create a `<style>` element with CSS textContent that overrides whatever you need overwritten or even rest, add it to the document: done. That new CSS wins, as long as its selectors are more specific, or you added `!important` as part of the text)

Comment: And of course, if you want code that can safely run while also being allowed to bypass CORS, write your [own browser extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_first_WebExtension) so you can pre-authorize all the normally-security-model-breaking behaviour.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I am just trying to read the loaded CSS (using the browser's console). Perhaps I should edit my question to make this more clear.